# call database connection variables from different classes

Tags: php, database, class

I'm starting on classes, and now I'm working on a project that involves several classes placed on different folders on the root, and each class connects to the same db.

Is there a way to store connection variables somewhere and get them on each class? (like an include option).

Been reading about class Customer (that's my example) extends myvariables, but I can't figure if that's the best practice.

Can you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a static class to do all of the database work for you, and expose the methods you need.

```
public static class DatabaseUtils
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "...";

    public static int GetCustomerId(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("sql stuff"))
            {
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result == DBNull.Value)
                    return -1;

                return (int) result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log errors  + ex
        }
    }

    // Other methods to interact with the database
}
```

You could then call a method like:

```
int id = DatabaseUtils.GetCustomerId("My", "Name");
```

If this is going to eventually be a deployed application, you might want to look at storing the connection string in the `app.config` so that it can be changed without recompiling the app.

Comment: the OP says php, right?

Comment: Wow so he did.  I was reading C# posts then came across this one.

Comment: well looks like he is happy with it.. so, so be it :)